# Creating several EJB Timer dynamic

Tags: java, timer, ejb, schedule

I am creating dynamic calendar timers in Java with `ScheduleExpression` and  `timerService.createCalendarTimer` from `@Resource`.

After the first execution tiggered by `@Timeout`, my timers are triggered  every second instead of the schedule I configured before.

How could I fixed this issue?

Comment: Please provide the  `ScheduleExpression` you used

Comment: ScheduleExpression se = new ScheduleExpression();
  se.year(*);
  se.month(*);
  se.dayOfMonth(*);
  se.dayOfWeek(*);
  se.hour(*);
  se.minute("*/10");
  se.second("*");
  
After post this question, I found the solution, but I don´t the reason.
I changed the ScheduleExpression to ScheduleExpression se = new ScheduleExpression();
  se.year(*);
  se.month(*);
  se.dayOfMonth(*);
  se.dayOfWeek(*);
  se.hour(*);
  se.minute("*/10");

And everything works perfect.
What was wrong?

Comment: Probably setting `se.second("*");` force to esecute each second whatever you set for mintues,hour etc... try with `se.second("0");`  . Btw do not put code in comment, edit your question or answer you own question if you find a soluction